# Rename empty package?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I rename empty package name in IDEA 11? I can rename only a package which has files in it.

For example, I have a package `com.example.test` with subfolder `parser.xml`. How can I rename `parser` folder? Pressing `Ctrl+F6` will only let me rename `xml` folder.

PS. What would happen if I open a system's file manager and rename a folder there? Will IDEA properly handle such renaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the gear icon in the Project view and disable the **Compact Empty Middle Packages** option. This way the project folders will be represented in a tree where each subfolder is a separate node, so that you can rename them individually.

> PS. What would happen if I open a system's file manager and rename a folder there? Will IDEA properly handle such renaming?

No, IDEA will not handle such rename as a refactoring and will not update any references.